# how to remove instances and possible multiple instances of a certain word in a string and return a string (CODEWARS dubstep)

Tags: python, string, replace, strip

I have had a go at the CODEWARS dubstep challenge using python.

My code is below, it works and I pass the kata test. However, it took me a long time and I ended up using a brute force approach (newbie).

(basically replacing and striping the string until it worked)

Any ideas with comments on how my code could be improved please?

TASK SUMMARY:

> Let's assume that a song consists of some number of words (that don't contain WUB). To make the dubstep remix of this song, Polycarpus inserts a certain number of words "WUB" before the first word of the song (the number may be zero), after the last word (the number may be zero), and between words (at least one between any pair of neighbouring words), and then the boy glues together all the words, including "WUB", in one string and plays the song at the club.
>
> For example, a song with words "I AM X" can transform into a dubstep remix as "WUBWUBIWUBAMWUBWUBX" and cannot transform into "WUBWUBIAMWUBX".
>
> `song_decoder("WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB")`
>   `# =>  WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND`
>
> `song_decoder("AWUBBWUBC")`, "A B C","WUB should be replaced by 1 space"
> `song_decoder("AWUBWUBWUBBWUBWUBWUBC")`, "A B C","multiples WUB should be replaced by only 1 space"
> `song_decoder("WUBAWUBBWUBCWUB")`, "A B C","heading or trailing spaces should be removed"

---

Thanks in advance, (I am new to stackoverflow also)

MY CODE:

```
def song_decoder(song):
new_song = song.replace("WUB", " ")
new_song2 = new_song.strip()
new_song3 = new_song2.replace("   ", "  ")
new_song4 = new_song3.replace("  ", " ")
return(new_song4)
```

Comment: Regex is an option: `def song_decoder(song): return re.sub("(WUB)+", ' ', song).strip()`

Comment: It failed when I used that function!   
test.assert_equals(song_decoder("AWUBBWUBC"), "A B C","WUB should be replaced by 1 space")
  File "/workspace/default/solution.py", line 2, in song_decoder
    return re.sub("(WUB)+", ' ', song).strip()
NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: You have to `import re` to use regex.

Comment: Thanks! Yes **import re** works :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it can improve it but I would use `split` and `join`

```
text = 'WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB'
text = text.replace("WUB", " ")
print(text)
words = text.split()
print(words)
text = " ".join(words)
print(text)
```

Result

```
 WE ARE  THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND 
['WE', 'ARE', 'THE', 'CHAMPIONS', 'MY', 'FRIEND']
WE ARE THE CHAMPIONS MY FRIEND
```

---

**EDIT:**

Dittle different version. I split usinsg `WUB` but then it creates empty elements between two `WUB` and it needs to remove them

```
text = 'WUBWEWUBAREWUBWUBTHEWUBCHAMPIONSWUBMYWUBFRIENDWUB'

words = text.split("WUB")
print(words)

words = [x for x in words if x]    # remove empty elements
#words = list(filter(None, words))  # remove empty elements
print(words)

text = " ".join(words)
print(text)
```

Comment: Yes it worked! Thank you :) My understanding is that the split function disregards any whitespace " ", including double or tripe whitespace "  ", "   " etc and simply puts actual text/string content into a list. Then the join method will join the list content as desired.

Comment: yes, `split()` splits on whitespaces (space, tab, enter) and works little different then using `split("WUB")` which creates empty elements between two `WUB`. See new example in code.